# Fine tuning regex to extract data between delimeters

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm using VBA regex and I need to extract only the data between two # delimters (I only need the text with any spaces before and after removed, not the # delimeters).

So far I have this pattern:

`^#\s*(.*)\s*#$`

The data entered has several rules:

```
1. Always start with #
2. After the first # there may be zero or one spaces
3. After captured text there may be zero or one spaces before end of line
4. After captured text there may be zero or one # before end of line
```

So for example:

```
# this is a test 
#this is a test
# this is a test#
# this is a test #
```

In all four cases `this is a test` should be the only thing returned.

I don't think the pattern is a million miles away however it seems to have difficulty when I add the ending # symbol along with / absence of spaces....

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may fix your current solution using

```
^#\s*(.*?)\s*#?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0hM3J1/1). Two main points: 1) `(.*?)` must be a lazy dot pattern, 2) `#?` now has a `?` quantifier to match `#` 1 or 0 times.

However, you may also remove the leading / trailing matches using `Replace` with

```
^#\s*|\s*#?$
```

pattern. Do not forget to set regex `.Global = True`.

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0hM3J1/2).

Comment: Yes, this seems to have fixed the problem.  Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @cosmarchy Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.